# (Vanilla) JS: Checkbox "checked" returning unexpected results

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Using the pen below you can see there are two elements, a button and a checkbox input.

When the button is clicked I would like to determine the status of checkbox (clicked/not-clicked).

Regardless of the visual check mark presence or not, the console always logs `false`. Why is this?

https://codepen.io/sterlingbutters/pen/ZEGGgvm

EDIT (code):

HTML:

```
<input id='stall' type="checkbox">

<button id='button'>Test
```

JS:

```
var stall = document.getElementById('stall').checked;
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.onclick = function () {
  console.log(stall);
}
```

Comment: You have to re-asign the value of stall when you click the button. Otherwise it will stay the initial value of the checkbox state during runtime

Comment: As Tracer69 said, you stored the value once outside the function when it was false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reasign stall on button click.
So Using

```
button.onclick = function () {
  var stall = document.getElementById('stall').checked
  console.log(stall);
}
```

It works fine.

Comment: Ahh yes this works - thank you for the speedy answer - I still can't accept it for another 8 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead: assign the element to the variable, and then inside your onclick function you get the `checked` property every time it runs.

If you just store the boolean value of `checked` in a variable, it will never update. Primitive types like booleans are always stored as simple values, not as auto-updating references back to the original property.

```js
var stall = document.getElementById('stall');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.onclick = function () {
  console.log(stall.checked);
}
```

```html
<input id='stall' type="checkbox">

<button id='button'>Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you assigned "stall", it won't be re-assiged in "button.onclick". You must re-assign, such as

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.onclick = function () {
  var stall = document.getElementById('stall').checked;
  console.log(stall);
}
```

or better

```
var stall = document.getElementById('stall');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.onclick = function () {
  console.log(stall.checked);
}
```